# Could not resolve dependencies error in maven

Tags: maven

I have a multi module maven project:

```
portlet
     mapadmin
util-java
     EngineService
     Shapeloader
     staticmap
```

mapadmin is child of portlet and EngineService, Shapeloader, staticmap is children of util-java.
I am using EngineService classes in staticmap and mapadmin. So I add a dependency of EngineService in staticmap and mapadmin :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>ir.nsdp.satra</groupId>
    <artifactId>EngineService</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

this dependency works in staticamp but it takes error in mapadmin(Could not resolve dependencies).
I have installed EngineService successfully and it appears in .m2 folder.

Exact error :

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project mapadmin-portlet: Could not resolve dependencies for project ir.nsdp.satra:mapadmin-portlet:war:1.0: Failed to collect dependencies at ir.nsdp.satra:EngineService:jar:1.0: Failed to read artifact descriptor for ir.nsdp.satra:EngineService:jar:1.0: Failure to find ir.nsdp.satra:Satra:pom:1.0 in http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
```

And this is my EngineService pom.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
    <artifactId>util-java</artifactId>
    <groupId>ir.nsdp.satra</groupId>
    <version>1.0</version>
  </parent>

    <artifactId>EngineService</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>Satra Utils</name>

    <prerequisites>
        <maven>${mavenVersion}</maven>
    </prerequisites>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <geotools.version>10.3</geotools.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.liferay.portal</groupId>
            <artifactId>portal-service</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
            <artifactId>gt-wms</artifactId>
            <version>${geotools.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ir.nsdp.satra</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapadmin-portlet-service</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>maven2-repository.dev.java.net</id>
            <name>Java.net repository</name>
            <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>osgeo</id>
            <name>Open Source Geospatial Foundation Repository</name>
            <url>http://download.osgeo.org/webdav/geotools/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <build>
    <finalName>satra-${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.7</source>
                        <target>1.7</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${basedir}/../../web/src/main/docroot/WEB-INF/lib</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

</project>
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Edit your question and add the exact error message that you get.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know all the details of the problem but try to do the following:

```
cd util-java
mvn install
cd ../portlet/mapadmin
mvn compile
```

Comment: What is the difference of installing EngineService itself and installing util-java ?  shapeloader needs jar of mapadmin and so that I can't install util-java withour having installed mapadmin

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the error message, you see this near the end:

```
 Failed to read artifact descriptor for ir.nsdp.satra:EngineService:jar:1.0:
 Failure to find ir.nsdp.satra:Satra:pom:1.0 in
 http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository,
 resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central
 has elapsed or updates are forced
```

That means that `ir.nsdp.satra:EngineService:jar:1.0` has a dependency `ir.nsdp.satra:Satra:pom:1.0`.

When Maven looked last time, this dependency was neither in `$HOME/.m2/repository` nor on Maven Central. It will try again tomorrow or when you run `mvn` with `--update-snapshots` (which will, unlike the name suggests, also look again for missing releases).

Try to run `mvn install` in the project which contains the missing POM.

Comment: I updated my first post and added EngineService pom. It don't have Satra dependency

Comment: If you don't have the Satra dependency, then how do you expect Maven to build the project? Should it just pull in some random code? :-) Either delete the dependency in your POM or install the dependency in your local .m2 repo.

Comment: I mean that I have not a dependency element that points to Satra. You can see my pom in first post

Comment: You do have this dependency, it's just not easy to see since it's transitive, i.e. you depend on something which needs `ir.nsdp.satra:Satra:pom:1.0`. My guess is that the parent POM `util-java` eventually asks for it.

Comment: Oh my god. That's the name of the parent project of portlet and util-java. So I need to mvn install of the parent of parent pom ?

Comment: Sure. You need to install everything that your project needs. A better solution might be to run a local Maven proxy that mirrors Central and has a copy of all internal releases. Then you can point Maven at it and it will happily download everything that is missing without you having install everything yourself.